# Should "Cyan Paint" act differently to all other paint?

Tags: terraria-console

Playing on Xbox 360, I have been really getting into the player-made houses, and am currently building a set of "showcase rooms" for my painter.

I have placed 16 2x2 segments of wooden wall to display the base colours, and framed them with stone, to display the deep colours. Everything is pretty much complete. However; Deep Cyan does not appear to paint stone. I know that some tiles can not be painted, but I understood that this was specific to the tile, not the paint. As you can see in my image, I had no trouble painting any of the other frames.

[image: As you can see, Cyan is displaying differently to all its neighbor colours.]

I have attempted to paint the stone with Deep Cyan twice. The first time, you could see the tiny paint drops flick out, confirming that I had painted something. The second time, I cleared out my inventory, to make sure I was not accidentally using a different paint. This time, no paint drops, and still no colour.

***Does Cyan/Deep Cyan Paint have different capabilities then every other paint, am I doing something wrong, or is this more likely just a bug?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a rendering bug that many people have reported.

Not only that but the saturation is incorrect (ie. it's the same as cyan).

However this should have been fixed in [version 1.3](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/1-3-changelog.20617/). So if you are running an earlier version try updating.

Comment: That makes sense. I believe 1.3 is not live to console, yet.